# Каково значение и происхождение слова "стрёмно"?

Tags: этимология, лексика

Слово "стрёмно" встречается в художественной литературе, но, по-моему, с разным значением, например:

Стрёмно как-то. Поймают ― в тюрьму попадешь (рискованно?).

Стоит наш монастырь и светится ― стрёмно (странно?) так светится, как гнилушки на болоте.

А каково происхождение этого слова, оно связано как-то со словами "стремиться, стремительный, стремглав"? Кажется, что между ними нет ничего общего, или это не так?

Comment: > Происходит от лат. tremor «дрожь, трепет», далее из tremere «дрожать,
> трепетать», далее из праиндоевр. *trem- «трясти, дрожать».

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно, в обоих случаях значения близки к «опасно», «страшно».

Происхождение этого жаргонизма — впрочем, как и многих других — неясно. Некоторые исследователи связывают его с немецким *Strom* «поток», «быстрое течение», что вызывает некоторые вопросы. Если их откинуть, тогда *стремить(ся)* — дальний родственник слова *стрем*, оба они восходят к общему праиндоевропейскому корню.

Answer (score 2):

*Стрёмно как-то. Поймают ― в тюрьму попадешь (рискованно?)*. **Нет, "страшно", "опасно".**

*Стоит наш монастырь и светится ― стрёмно (странно?) так светится, как гнилушки на болоте.* **И здесь "страшно".**

*"Стоять на стрёме"* - знаете? Или "на шухере". Шухер - опасность, из "Джентльменов удачи" известно. )

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю это слово произошло от слова "стремена". Так же как и слово "стремянка".
Когда всадник встает на стремена, он получает возможность оглядеться поверх высокой травы и кустов. Отсюда пошло выражение стоять на стрёме (имхо). И говорить "стоять на стреме" неудобно. Так "е" заменилась на "ё" чисто из разговорной практики. Потом возникло и слово "стрёмно". Значит высоко, неудобно, напряженно.

Answer (score 0):

Trom - край обрыва (Норвежский, другие скандинавские и северо-германские). Ходить по краю.